# Excel: Lookup matching cell in a table and return the value of the first cell in the row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is a picture to demonstrate:

[image]

So from this, we can see Item 9 belongs to Category C. I want to find a formulas to automate this process. Where if I provide excel with a number, say 12, it will be able to give me "D."

Unfortunately, this is not possible with VLookUp nor HLookUp as they require the matching value to be on the left side of the table. I've tried with Index / Match, but that seems to spit out an error instead.

Am I approaching this wrong? Should I reformat the table or is there a better formula to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use INDEX with AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$E$5)/($B$2:$E$5 = 12),1))
```

You can change the `12` to a cell reference to make it more dynamic.

[image]

Comment: That's very clever. Thank you for that. Now, going beyond that, what if there are two entries of 12, one in category A and the other in Category D, would excel be able to find both and return A and D?

Comment: Sure, but technically that is a new question, but you would use Row(1:1) in the place of the `1` at the end of the formula.

Comment: Then as you drag the formula down it will pick up the next one.

Comment: Amazing. I hope one day I'll reach your level of excel mastery :) Thank you so much Scott!